# The exterior derivative of a $k$-form as a multilinear function

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $w$ be a $k$-form, then it can be viewed as a multilinear function of vector fields of the manifold. $dw$ is a $k+1$ form thus a multilinear function on vector fields as well. Given vector fields $X_1, \ldots, X_{k+1}$. I want to know what is $dw(X_1, \ldots, X_{k+1})$ in terms of $w$. This can be derived of course directly via the alternating tensor formulas and induction. However, the computation is sort of tedious. Is there an easier way to compute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if my answer is what you are looking for but:

$$d\varepsilon(X_1, \ldots, X_{k+1})=\sum_{\sigma\in \mathsf{Sh}(1, k)} \mathsf{sgn}(\sigma) X_{\sigma(1)} \varepsilon(X_{\sigma(2)}, \ldots, X_{\sigma(k+1)})+\sum_{\sigma\in\mathsf{Sh}(2, k-1)} \mathsf{sgn}(\sigma) \varepsilon([X_{\sigma(1)}, X_{\sigma(2)}], X_{\sigma(3)}, \ldots, X_{\sigma(k+1)})$$

where $\mathsf{Sh}(p, q)$ is the set of those permutations $\sigma$ of the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, p+q\}$ such that

$$\sigma(1)<\ldots<\sigma(p)\quad \textrm{and}\quad \sigma(p+1)<\ldots<\sigma(p+q).$$